# Flutter_test can't find widgets after it mounts my custom widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement a simple widget test with Flutter_test library. I got an error <Found 0 widgets with type "TextFormField": []> but it should be there, so as I understand Login doesn't mount, but can't figure out why. Do you have any ideas what should I change?
my test is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dnd/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Verify that we will got an error on wrong email input',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: Login()));
      var textField = find.byType(TextFormField);
      expect(textField, findsNWidgets(2));
    }
  );
}
```

My Login widget is

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import '../firebase_options.dart';
import '../utils/fireAuth.dart';
import '../utils/validators.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dnd/providers/authProvider.dart';

class Login extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends ConsumerState<Login> {
  String email = '';
  String password = '';

  Future<FirebaseApp?>? firebaseInit;

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseInit = _initializeFirebase();
  }

  Future<FirebaseApp?> _initializeFirebase() async {
    try {
      FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
      return firebaseApp;
    } catch (e) {
      print('ERROR ${e}');
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: const Text('Login'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: firebaseInit,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return Center(
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  TextFormField(
                                    key: const ValueKey('email'),
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Email",
                                      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.red,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    validator: (value) => Validator.validateEmail(
                                      email: value,
                                    ),
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        email = value;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16)),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: "Password",
                                      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6.0),
                                        borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.red,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    validator: (value) => Validator.validatePassword(
                                      password: value,
                                    ),
                                    onChanged: (String value) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        password = value;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16)),
                                  ElevatedButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                          void callback(bool value) => ref.read(isAuthenticated.notifier).update((state) => value);
                                          FireAuth.signInWithEmail(email: email, password: password, callback: callback);
                                        }
                                      },
                                      child: const Text('Login')
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/signUp');
                                      },
                                      child: const Text('Sign up'))
                                ],
                              )
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                );
              }
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
        )
    );
  }
```

And here is main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dnd/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dnd/screens/signup.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dnd/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dnd/providers/authProvider.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await dotenv.load();

  runApp(ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => const MainScreen(),
          '/signUp': (context) => const SignUp(),
        },
      ),
  ));
}

class MainScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final authState = ref.watch(isAuthenticated);
    if (authState) {
      return const GameChat();
    }
    return const Login();
  }
}
```

Comment: Share your pubspec.yaml so that I can try and fix your issue on my local machine

Comment: If you share your project as a zip it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reason. I had to initialise firebase first.
So I created a file mock.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

typedef Callback = void Function(MethodCall call);

void setupFirebaseAuthMocks([Callback? customHandlers]) {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  setupFirebaseCoreMocks();
}

Future<T> neverEndingFuture<T>() async {
  // ignore: literal_only_boolean_expressions
  while (true) {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 5));
  }
}
```

and then added this code in main function before test

```
setupFirebaseAuthMocks();

setUpAll(() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
});
```